# highcharts shared tooltips pointer

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that displays all sorts of weather data and it does that correctly.

The tooltips work fine on the data within the series but I want to add some additional data in the form of additional text to each one from another data array.

The first data array is

```
var hightemp = new Array(12.2, 12.9, 22.7, 26.0, 29.8, 31.5
                        ,33.5, 30.5, 25.1, 23.6, 15.2, 13.2);
```

and the second is

```
var hightempT = new Array("at 16:44 on 29 January 2013"
                  , "at 13:58 on 29 February 2012", "at 18:03 on 28 March 2012"
                  , "at 17:44 on 21 April 2011", "at 17:08 on 26 May 2012"
                  , "at 17:22 on 26 June 2011", "at 17:10 on 26 July 2012"
                  , "at 17:06 on 10 August 2012", "at 18:10 on 07 September 2012"
                  , "at 14:55 on 01 October 2011", "at 13:53 on 03 November 2011"
                  , "at 14:13 on 22 December 2012");
```

So when a tooltip runs across point 1 it currently reads `HT : 12.2C` and I want it to read `HT : 12.2C at 16:44 on 29 January 2013` by accessing the same position in the 2nd array and adding the script to the end of the tooltip. What I need to know is what pointer variable is pointing at position 1 in array 1 so I can use it to access the appropriate data in array 2?

Additional data.

Ok I have formatted a variable as you suggested

```
var hightemp = new Array(
                         { y:12.2, time:"at 16:44 on 29 January 2013"},
                         { y:12.9, time:"at 13:58 on 29 February 2012"},
                         { y:22.7, time:"at 18:03 on 28 March 2012"},
                         { y:26.0, time:"at 17:44 on 21 April 2011"},
                         { y:29.8, time:"at 17:08 on 26 May 2012"},
                         { y:31.5, time:"at 17:22 on 26 June 2011"},
                         { y:33.5, time:"at 17:10 on 26 July 2012"},
                         { y:30.5, time:"at 17:06 on 10 August 2012"},
                         { y:25.1, time:"at 18:10 on 07 September 2012"},
                         { y:23.6, time:"at 14:55 on 01 October 2011"},
                         { y:15.2, time:"at 13:53 on 03 November 2011"},
                         { y:13.2, time:"at 14:13 on 22 December 2012"}
                        );
```

but the code

```
        formatter: function() {
            return 'HT:'+ this.y + this.x + this.time;
```

in the tooltip gives `HT:12.2Janundefined`, so it has found `y` & `x` but not the time in the array above

Using `point.x` as you suggested the code produces nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two arrays. Format your data points as follows:

```
[{ y:12.2, text:"at 16:44 on 29 January 2013"},
 { y:12.9, text:"at 13:58 on 29 February 2012"}
...
 ]
```

In the tooltip function, you can now access the point y and text attributes. An example of using a tooltip is http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-simple/

If you setup your points as I suggest, you could reference this.point.text in the formatter function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my data is coming from a weather program and is already formatted as I indicated and it would be a lot of work to reformat it. Is there no way just to point at the other array i.e hightempT[point]?

Comment: Try looking at the point x value in the tooltip. They may number 0,1.2.3 etc

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by this "In the tooltip function, you can now access the point y and text attributes.", please?

Comment: Updated my question after trying out a test variable formatted as you suggested, Steve. Sorry to be a pain!!